# Calculus: Area Between Two Curves

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area between the two curves $y = x^2 + ax$ and $y = 2x$ between $x=1$ and $x=2$, given that $a>2$

I found the antiderivative of $x^2+ax-2x$ and included the area between $x=1$ and $x=2$ which is $\dfrac{3a-4}{6}-\dfrac{6a-4}{3}$. I don't understand what $(a>2)$ means in the problem.

Comment: $(a>2)$ is not part of the second equation, if that is part of the confusion? it is a separate part.

Comment: Oh.  When I was editing the question, I implemented Dre's suggestion without thinking.  If that is the confusion, please edit it back to the way it was...

Comment: the (a>2) is written right next to the "y=2x" part of the question. I don't why it's there or what how to incorporate it

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  the area between two curves $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can be found by the formula 
$$A=\int_c^d{[f(x)-g(x)]dx}$$

It seems the reason it's asking you for $a>2$ is it will cancel the $2x$ if $a=2$.  Perhaps you should plot the graphs for different values of $a$.

Comment: I have used that however I still have "a" in the answer. I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: The $a$ is just an arbitrary scalar.  If it equals 2 your $x^2+ax-2x$ just becomes $x^2$ and they probably are trying you to work with multiple terms and arbitrary scalers.

Comment: Unfortunately it is asking me for a final answer on the website. I tried entering it with the "a" still in the answer and it doesn't accept it. How can I get a single answer when "a" is anything from greather than 2 to infinity?

Comment: Did you integrate properly?  I got $\frac{7}{3}+\frac{3(a-2)}{2}$

Comment: Having $a$ is completely acceptable in the answer if it gives you something like $a>2$.  I suspect you are missing something critical or you made a calculation error.

Comment: That was the problem. I only had the 7/3. I still don't understand where I went wrong unfortunately.

Comment: The $a$ is simply a constant but it takes on the disguise of a variable since it can be any value, in your case, it must be greater than 2.  Arbitrary scalars and variables pop up in higher mathematics.  Since the calculation does not require you to know a specific value, you treat it as if it were just a number, like 3 or $\pi$.  Don't worry if it hangs around in the solution because it' supposed to be there